# Quora styled "add content" icon in Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

Using Jquery Mobile, I am trying to emulate what quora has done with its "Add Question" button. The Add Question button is a simple floating '**+**' aligned centrally in the bottom.

[image]

To emulate the same for my app I have created a transparent footer with ui-grid-b and placed the plus icon in the block-b

```
       <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <h3>
                <div class="ui-grid-b">
                    <div class="ui-block-a" style="text-align: left;"></div>
                    <div class="ui-block-b" style="text-align: center;">
                    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="flat-plus" class="ui-nodisc-icon"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-c" style="text-align: right;"></div>                
                </div><!-- /grid-a -->
            </h3>                
        </div>
```

With the theme  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); I do have a plus mark in the bottom, but nothing close to what Quora has been able to do.

My solution does not allow the users to touch and slide anywhere in the footer - while the quora app has no such qualms. The plus button is almost an island of its own. How can I achieve something like this with JQM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a footer, just use an inline button and then add some CSS to center it and fix it to the bottom of the page:

Button markup (added bottomCenter class):

```
<a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all bottomCenter">Add</a>
```

CSS for bottomCenter class:

```
.bottomCenter {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
    bottom: 4px;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
```

A high z-index keeps it floating above other content, the rest sets the position to fixed at bottom center.

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/me88S/)**